# Flutter sqflite insert List<String>

Tags: sql, flutter, visual-studio-code, sqflite

i'm trying to insert a List into a sql database in flutter , but i dont know how can i do it , can anyone help me ?

i have this when i initialize mi database:

```
Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "tuCuestionarioDB.db");
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onOpen: (db) {},
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute("CREATE TABLE Question ("
          "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
          "subject INTEGER,"
          "topic INTEGER,"
          "question TEXT,"
          "answer INTEGER,"
          "answers TEXT ARRAY," //THIS IS MY LIST<STRING>
          "rightAnswer INTEGER,"
          "correctly BIT,"
          "answered BIT"
          ")");
    });
```

and i have this to insert data:

```
 newQuestion(Question newQuestion) async {
     final db = await database;
    //get the biggest id in the table
    var table = await db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(id)+1 as id FROM Question");
    int id = table.first["id"];
    //insert to the table using the new id
    var raw = await db.rawInsert(
        "INSERT Into Question (id,subject,topic,question,answer,answers,rightAnswer,correctly,answered)"
        " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
        [id != null ? id : 0, newQuestion.subject, newQuestion.topic,newQuestion.question,newQuestion.answer,newQuestion.answers,newQuestion.rightAnswer,newQuestion.correctly ? 1 : 0,newQuestion.answered ? 1 : 0]);
    return raw;
  }
```

but when y try to insert a value like this:

```
{subject: 1, topic: 1, question: What is the best community?, answer: 3, rightAnswer: 0, answers: [Stack Overflow, Facebook, Yahoo Answers], correctly: false, answered: false}
```

i got a error like this:

> Exception has occurred.
>
> SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(java.lang.String cannot be
>   cast to java.lang.Integer) sql 'INSERT Into Question
>   (id,subject,topic,question,answer,answers,rightAnswer,correctly,answered)
>   VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)' args [0, 1, 1, What is the best
>   community?, 3, [Stack Overflow, Facebook, Answers Yahoo], 0, 0, 0]})

and when i remove anwsers field i got no erros

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you cannot store a list of strings in this way. According to the [docs](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/supported_types.md), it only supports a blob of ints. I think there are two ways you could do this.

One way would be to stringify the answers into a single string. You can use the [join](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/Iterable/join.html) method and separate it by a character that no answer will contain (maybe a pipe like |). Then, when you read from the database, you can [split](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/String/split.html) the string back into an array using the character you chose.

The other way to do this would be to create a table that associates a single question with multiple answers. This is basically sudo code, but if you had a table that matched this it should work.

```
Answer

int id autoincremented, int questionId, String answerText, int isCorrectAnswer (0 or 1)
```

Also, a bit unrelated, but sqflite supports the AUTOINCREMENT keyword which I recommend you use for your primary key IDs.