# SQFLite (Flutter) Insert fails for Map containing Maps

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

Can someone confirm if SQFLite supports maps containing maps?  I did run across the following post on this site and possibly this is the answer?

[Flutter sqflite insert List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58633648/flutter-sqflite-insert-liststring)

In my situation, I have a two model classes I am working with.

- House
- Dog

House includes a field called pets which is a List

I have a constructor and factory method in each of these classes which takes care of converting to/from map/object as needed for sending to and retrieving information from SQFLite.

Model classes
Dog

```
class Dog {
  final int id;
  final String breed;
  final String name;
  final int age;

  Dog({this.id, this.breed, this.name, this.age});

  // Used when inserting a row into the db, including the id field
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final map = Map<String, dynamic>();
    map['id'] = id;
    map['breed'] = breed;
    map['name'] = name;
    map['age'] = age;
    return map;
  }

  // Used when returning a row from the DB and converting into an object
  factory Dog.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) => Dog(
      id: data['id'],
      breed: data['breed'],
      name: data['name'],
      age: data['age']
  );
}
```

House

```
import 'dog.dart';

class House{
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String color;
  final List<Dog> pets;

  House({this.id, this.name, this.color, this.pets});

  // Will be used when inserting a row into the database
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final map = Map<String, dynamic>();
    map['id'] = id;
    map['name'] = name;
    map['color'] = color;
    if (this.pets != null) {
      map['pets'] = this.pets.map((pet) => pet.toMap()).toList();
    }
    return map;
  }

  // Used when returning a row from the DB and converting into an object
  factory House.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return House(
      id: data['id'],
      name: data['name'],
      color: data['color'],
      pets: data['pets'] != null
          ? (data['pets'] as List).map((pet) => Dog.fromMap(pet)).toList()
          : null,
    );
  }
}
```

Method for inserting a new house

```
Future<int> addNewHome(House house) async {
    // Attempt to add the house to the DB
    var client = await database.db;
    int result = await client.insert(HomesSchema.tblHomes, house.toMap(), conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
    _homes.add(house);
    return result;
  }
```

When I attempt to perform the insert, I get the following error.

```
E/flutter (  586): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer) sql 'INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO homes (id, name, color, pets) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' args [1, Smith, Green, [{name: Mackie, id: 1, breed: Rottweiler, age: 8}, {name: Tanner, id: 2, breed: Mastiff, age: 8}]]}
E/flutter (  586): #0      wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/exception_impl.dart:12:7)
E/flutter (  586): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (  586): #1      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl.wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/factory_impl.dart:25:7)
E/flutter (  586): #2      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.safeInvokeMethod (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:188:15)
E/flutter (  586): #3      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnRawInsert.<anonymous closure> (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:363:14)
E/flutter (  586): #4      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnSynchronized.<anonymous closure> (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:307:22)
E/flutter (  586): #5      BasicLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:32:26)
E/flutter (  586): #6      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnSynchronized (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:303:43)
E/flutter (  586): #7      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnWriteSynchronized (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:325:7)
E/flutter (  586): #8      SqfliteDatabaseMixin.txnRawInsert (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:362:12)
E/flutter (  586): #9      SqfliteDatabaseExecutorMixin.rawInsert (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:49:15)
E/flutter (  586): #10     SqfliteDatabaseExecutorMixin.insert (package:sqflite/src/database_mixin.dart:59:12)
E/flutter (  586): #11     Homes.addNewHome (package:search_list_view/providers/homes.dart:19:31)
E/flutter (  586): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (  586): #12     _MyAppState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:search_list_view/main.dart:95:26)
E/flutter (  586): #13     _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
E/flutter (  586): #14     _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36)
E/flutter (  586): #15     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter (  586): #16     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11)
E/flutter (  586): #17     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5)
E/flutter (  586): #18     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:199:7)
E/flutter (  586): #19     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:467:9)
E/flutter (  586): #20     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:76:12)
E/flutter (  586): #21     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:117:9)
E/flutter (  586): #22     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
E/flutter (  586): #23     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:115:18)
E/flutter (  586): #24     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:7)
E/flutter (  586): #25     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
E/flutter (  586): #26     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter (  586): #27     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (  586): #28     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter (  586): #29     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (  586): #30     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)
E/flutter (  586): #31     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter (  586): #32     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter (  586): #33     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:273:10)
E/flutter (  586): #34     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:5)
E/flutter (  586):
```

If the answer is to change my DB schema so I have a table which joins dogs and houses and then do a custom query to pull back the information I'm after, then fine, I will do that.  It doesn't seem too far fetch that a nosql db should be able to handle this... yes/no?

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Bob

Comment: no, sqlite supports the same types that normal sqlite does - so you cannot use a map as a table column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For storing any kind of value in the SQLite Database you can simply serialize the object into a JSON string and later deserialize the object.
lets say you have a class called Menu. (I am using JSON serializable here)

```
   class Menu {

   @JsonKey(name: "status")
   String status;
   @JsonKey(name: "data")
   MenuListData menuListData;

   Menu(this.status, this.menuListData);
   factory Menu.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> 
   json)=>_$MenuFromJson(json);
   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MenuToJson(this);

 }
```

Here is how to encode it in JSON and store it(in your bloc).

```
   Menue menuList =
    await getIt<LiveMenuRepository>().getMenuResponse(menuPost);

    //decode the response to String format
    String menuResponseString = jsonEncode(menuList);

    //convert the string to Map of <String,dynamic> format

    Map<String, dynamic> menuResponseMap = {"menu": menuResponseString};

    //store this Map response in to local database
    int menuStored = await getIt<LocalMenuRepository>().insertMenuResponseData(menuResponseMap);
```

Your DB insertion method

```
Future<int> insertMenuResponseData(Map<String,dynamic> menuResponse) async {
final db = await dbProvider.database;
var result = db.insert(menuTable, menuResponse);
return result;
}
```

Later retrieve your object using this

```
final Map<String, dynamic> menuList = await getIt<LocalMenuRepository>().getMenuResponseString();
  //  if(menuList!=null) {
      menuList.forEach((key, value) {
        if (key == "menu") {
          storedMenu = value ;
        }
      });
      //decode the string back to Map Object
      final dynamic menuMap = jsonDecode(storedMenu);

      //getting the Menu object using fromJson method

      final Menu menuListNameResponse = Menu
          .fromJson(menuMap as Map<String,dynamic>);
```

//getMenuResponseString method in db

```
Future<Map<String,dynamic>> getMenuResponse() async {
final db = await dbProvider.database;

List<Map<String, dynamic>> result;

result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $menuTable');
// print(result[0]);

if (result.length > 0) {

  return result[0];
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: The main question I had I believe is answered via your post - in that, what I am trying to accomplish is do-able by serializing the objects.  Am I correct that by using dart convert in my project that I can leave my model class as is where one of the fields is a List of another object?  In my case, the House model class where one of its fields is a List of Dog objects?  From that, I should be able to use dart convert to serialize the object into a string which could then be inserted / updated into my DB?  Thank you for the response, very much appreciated.

Comment: @bboursaw73 exactly!! you will be able to store the list of any object using the serialization way.

Answer (score 1):

Supported types are listed here (num, String or Uint8List): https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/supported_types.md

Nested content is not supported, Map and List should be encoded in a supported type for example as json string.

Comment: So from a 'best practices' standpoint, would it be better to keep my model classes as/is, keeping the List<Dog> field in it? (Then get it into a format suitable for db as in json format, as explained above?) Or, would it be best to remove that and then just handle the mapping of dogs to house via raw queries?  Just trying to learn and understand best practices for handling this type situation.  Thank you.